# Set weight for NSFont

Tags: cocoa, fonts

I am looking for a simpler way to set a weight for `NSFont`.

Right now I can only do:

```
void SetWeight(NSFont font, int weight)
{
   NSFontManager *manager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
   int currentWeight = [manager weightOfFont:font];
   while( currentWeight != weight )
   {
      if( currentWeight >= weight )
      {
         [manager convertWeight:NO ofFont:font];
         currentWeight--;
      }
      else
      {
          [manager convertWeight:YES ofFont:font];
          currentWeight++;
      }
   }
}
```

Is there an easier way to set the appropriate weight for NSFont? Specifically I'm looking for eliminating the loop

Answer (score 4):

Does this method from the [NSFontManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontmanager) fit for this purpose?

```
- (NSFont *)fontWithFamily:(NSString *)family
                    traits:(NSFontTraitMask)fontTraitMask
                    weight:(NSInteger)weight
                      size:(CGFloat)size
```

Comment: But this method will recreate the font whereas I am looking for just setting the weight.

Comment: is it bad just to create new font object instead of using old one?

Answer (score 1):

For a button for example

```
button.font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:13 weight:NSFontWeightMedium];
```